# CSS best practice regarding classes and ids

Tags: css, class

New here. I am currently building a personal website with HTML & CSS (following MDN course).

CSS styling can make sheets quite lengthy.

Is it a good practice to style "reusable components" (using classes) and then using "id" to slightly alter such components?

Below code example + visual.

Thanks for the help!

```
.block { /* use of class for the block component */
  background-color: var(--darkest-green);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

#block_webpages { /* use of ID to adjust needed properties */
  background-color: var(--darkest-green);
}

#block_articles { /* use of ID to adjust needed properties */
  background-color: var(--light-green)
}

#block_about { /* use of ID to adjust needed properties */
  background-color: var(--green);
}
```

```
<div class = "block" id = "block_webpages">Introduction of the different web pages</div>
<div class = "block" id = "block_articles">About the website's author</div>
<div class = "block" id = "block_about">Shows the latest published article</div>
```

[rendering on the webpage - very basic element for demo purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InUny.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id's are more powerful selectors than class. It is advisable to use class not id for better programming or coder. (there are many other reasons also)
You can do the same thing with the class itself without giving id.

Good that you are using CSS variable naming property